# extracting values from text file using awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have 100 text files which look like this:

```
File title
4
Realization number
variable 2 name
variable 3 name
variable 4 name
1   3452  4538   325.5
```

The first number on the 7th line (1) is the realization number, which SHOULD relate to the file name. i.e. The first file is called file1.txt and has realization number 1 (as shown above). The second file is called file2.txt and should have realization number 2 on the 7th line. file3.txt should have realization number 3 on the 7th line, and so on...

Unfortunately every file has realization=1, where they should be incremented according to the file name.

I want to extract variables 2, 3 and 4 from the 7th line (3452, 4538 and 325.5) in each of the files and append them to a summary file called summary.txt.

I know how to extract the information from 1 file:

```
awk 'NR==7,NR==7{print $2, $3, $4}' file1.txt
```

Which, correctly gives me:

```
3452 4538 325.5
```

My first problem is that this command doesn't seem to give the same results when run from a bash script on multiple files.

```
#!/bin/bash    
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++));do
    awk 'NR=7,NR==7{print $2, $3, $4}' File$((i)).txt
done
```

I get multiple lines being printed to the screen when I use the above script.

Secondly, I would like to output those values to the summary file along with the CORRECT preceeding realization number. i.e. I want a file that looks like this:

```
1  3452  4538  325.5
2  4582  6853  158.2
...
100  4865 3589  15.15
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify some things and get the result you're after:

```
#!/bin/bash    

for ((i=1;i<=100;i++))
do
    echo $i $(awk 'NR==7{print $2, $3, $4}' File$i.txt)
done
```

You really don't want to assign to NR=7 (as you did) and you don't need to repeat the `NR==7,NR==7` either.  You also really don't need the `$((i))` notation when `$i` is sufficient.

If all the files are exactly 7 lines long, you can do it all in one `awk` command (instead of 100 of them):

```
awk 'NR%7==0 { print ++i, $2, $3, $4}' Files*.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. The first bit actually didn't work for me. I was getting substitution errors or syntax errors or something. However, the second 1 line command worked well for me. Thanks!

Comment: That's odd; the only way I could see running into problems is if you didn't actually have 100 files.  I tried it with 10 files and it seemed to work fine with both Bash 3.2 and 4.2.  However, I'm glad the one-liner worked; it is neater anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you have only one `=` in your bash script. Does all the files have exactly 7 lines? If you are only interested in the 7th line then:

```
#!/bin/bash    
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++));do
    awk 'NR==7{print $2, $3, $4}' File$((i)).txt
done
```

Since your realization number starts from 1, you can simply add that using `nl` command.

For example, if your bash script is called `s.sh` then:

```
./s.sh | nl > summary.txt
```

will get you the result with the expected lines in `summary.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==7 { print ++i, $2, $3, $4 > "summary.txt" }' $(ls -v file*)
```

The `-v` flag simply sorts the glob by version numbers. If your version of `ls` doesn't support this flag, try: `ls file* | sort -V` instead.